# SQLite query for Full Text Search to MATCH on both sides like LIKE

Tags: android, sqlite, fts3

I am having an issue for both side MATCH in SQLite FTS in Android.

Say suppose I have this text item in my VIRTUAL FTS TABLE

1. Hello World I am here
2. HelloWorld I am Here
3. HelloWorldIamHere

I want to achieve that for Search String **'World'** I should get all this ***THREE*** results.

I am able to achieve that using **LIKE** and **%** wildcard as **`WHERE column LIKE '%World%'`** but that is not meant to use as data grows. So I am using **MATCH** and ***** wildcard with Full Text Search Virtual Table as **`WHERE column MATCH 'World*'`**

BUT with this i am ***just getting this*** result...

1. Hello World I am here

How should i implement my MATCH query to get all the three items as my result

Answer (score 2):

FTS allows you to search only for terms generated by the [tokenizer](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#tokenizer).

There is no information in the FTS index that would allow fast searching for suffixes.
You have to use LIKE, or construct your own index manually.